# Send form via AJAX but only after validation returns true

Tags: jquery, ajax, onsubmit

I have an `onsubmit` validation in my form which works, yet my ajax file is still making a http request.

Here's the form:

```
<form class="ajax" action="mecha.php" name="ajax" method="post" onsubmit="return answer_validate(document.forms.ajax);">
    <input type="text" name="user_answer">
    <input type="submit" class="submit">
</form>
```

Here's the validation function that is triggered `onsubmit`:

```
function answer_validate(f) { 

    if (f.user_answer.value.length > 23 || f.user_answer.value.length < 1) {

        document.getElementById("notice").innerHTML = "please input an answer";

    return false; 
    }

return true;
}
```

Finally here's the AJAX file that is sending the form (even if the validation function returns false, which is the problem!):

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function() {

var that = $(this),
url  = that.attr('action'),
type = that.attr('method'),
data = {};

that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
    var that  = $(this),
        name  = that.attr('name'),
        value = that.val();
        data[name] = value;
});

$.ajax({
    url : url,
    type: type,
    data: data,
    success: function(response) {
        $('.output').html(response);
    }

});

return false;
});
```

So in summary, the form is validated with a `function` that returns either `true` or `false`. On submission the AJAX is still sending the form even when the validation returns false. Why is the AJAX still sending the form no matter what?

I have tried this example without sending the form via AJAX and the `onsubmit` works as normal, (halting form submission until validation returns true).

So what am I missing?

Comment: Why on earth are you mixing plain javascript and jquery in such way? `document.getElementById`? Why not just `$('#notice')`?

Comment: disable the onsubmit call for ajax and simply call the ajax inside the validation success function when validation returns true

Comment: @MightyPork Yeah silly right, I'm in the process of learning javascript from scratch because I've been using to much jquery, I just want to understand how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should call `answer_validate()` function inside  `$('form.ajax').on('submit', ....)` section.. inside jQuery `submit` event same form submit event also using, see below

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function(e) {

if(!answer_validate(this)){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    return false;
}

/*ajax part*/

})
```

**Updated answer**
ok, add `e.preventDefault();` outside if condition.. see below,

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();     
  if(!answer_validate(this)){
    return false;
  }

  /*ajax part*/

})
```

and use this condition `if($.trim(f.user_answer.value).length > 23 || $.trim(f.user_answer.value).length == 1)`

```
function answer_validate(f) { 
    if ($.trim(f.user_answer.value).length > 23 || 
        $.trim(f.user_answer.value) == "") {

        document.getElementById("notice").innerHTML = "please input an answer";
    return false; 
    }
return true;
}
```

**PS**: use `$.trim()` function to remove white space

Comment: Yes but the page is redirecting to mecha.php why?

Comment: use `e.preventDefault();` in case validation false and remove `osubmit` from form elelemt, see update answer..

Comment: I have removed the `onsubmit` and added this code, although now it returns false every time and the form can never submit

Comment: did you put value upto `24` in `user_answer` field

Comment: No I tried just entering the form so that it is < 1

Comment: `(f.user_answer.value.length > 23 || f.user_answer.value.length < 1)` your `IF` condition will reach upto `24` then `return true`

Comment: I'm returning false if the users input is over 23 characters in length or 0 in length, I'm returning true if in between then I want the AJAX to submit, but that's the moment it redirects to mecha.php instead of grabbing the response and slotting it into `$('.output').html(response);` (see original code) weird.

Comment: ok, add `e.preventDefault();` outside if condition.., and use this condition `if($.trim(f.user_answer.value).length > 23 || $.trim(f.user_answer.value).length == 1)` see updated answer

Comment: That did it! Thank-you for your perseverance. So I'm guessing it was not counting a white space? Do you mind explaining exactly what you did there in lay mans terms, as I want to learn, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
function answer_validate(f) { 

    if (f.user_answer.value.length > 23 || f.user_answer.value.length < 1) {

        document.getElementById("notice").innerHTML = "please input an answer";

    f.preventDefault(); 
    }
}
```

This could be enough, i believe return false is deprecated... 
if this doesn't work you could also check it in the on submit event handler

```
    $('form.ajax').on('submit', function(event) {

    if (event.user_answer.value.length > 23 || event.user_answer.value.length < 1) {

        document.getElementById("notice").innerHTML = "please input an answer";

    event.preventDefault(); 
    }else {
    var that = $(this),
    url  = that.attr('action'),
    type = that.attr('method'),
    data = {};

    that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
        var that  = $(this),
            name  = that.attr('name'),
            value = that.val();
            data[name] = value;
    });

    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            $('.output').html(response);
        }

    });

}
    });
```

Comment: All of these answers work yet the page is redirecting to mecha.php the idea is to retrive the response `$('.output').html(response);`

Comment: ohhh it isn't supposed to redirect then you should always put in event.preventDefault(); at the end of your function

Comment: Nope still redirects.